# How to add css classes into a specific image field in responsive edit mode

Tags: nodes, entities, media, theming

I have created a custom content type that has an **image field** which is required for each of this node type.

It works well in desktop mode. But not so in **responsive mode**.

So when a person is editing a node of that type **in a smartphone of tablet**, the **select image button** changes to a simple text "Attach a file". And nothing clearly indicates the user that it is a button.

**So I want to edit my css in order to change the view of that text to a button when the screen comes to responsive mode**.

**The question is : What it the class or ID that that I must access to do that ?**

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple custom module to alter the image field, To add a class or any other changes.

```
function MYMODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'page_node_form') {
    //Adds a class to 'my image' field in the node edit form of content-type page.
    //print_r($form);
    $form['field_my_image']['#prefix']=''; //div class="myclass_name"
    $form['field_my_image']['#suffix']='';//Close div here
    //OR
    $form['field_my_image']['#attributes']['class'][]='myclass_name';
  }
}
```

Then use media queries for class 'myclass_name' in your CSS file.

Comment: Tank you for the answer. I'll try this...